# What can I do about my domains history?

Tags: domains

I have just got my first domain from `godaddy.com` but looking at [web of trust](https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/triangularcircle.com?utm_source=addon&utm_content=rw-viewsc) my domain was once owned by a spammer and has a low rating.

On web of trust I can ask the community to reevaluate the site, but what about other sites that give domain ratings? What sites give ratings of domain names and what can I do about them? Also how can I check if Google has blacklisted my domain?

Comment: Get Google Authorship and fb graph to build credibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do, is launch the new site, with legal content.

You can use their tool to rate the site with high ranking and that will compensate for the bad preceding reputation. Of course you should leave a good comment and be sure that the date and comment reflect the change on direction of the website.

No need to mention that you are the owner of the site, In this case, the opinion of the owner has less value than other users.

Of course, you should have good content and not just a poor site.

About other sites, try to find references to your site on Internet. Be thorough.

Comment: There is a comment on web of trust saying that the site is spam, I have verified the site as mine on web of trust which gives me the ability to reply to comments should I reply to the comment explaining the situation?

Comment: I would also check the various blacklists for other reasons. WOT does not carry as much weight as you may think. Work on a good reputation of course. but also do not forget the blacklists which can really effect your work. http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx This should help. You can request to be removed from most blacklists. Some take as much as year or as little as two weeks if not. Who knows what you will see. It will take a while to regain a positive reputation, but it should all work out okay. Just do honest work and you will be fine.

Comment: @closetnoc I just checked multiple blacklists and its all clear :)

Comment: You can comment, but consider that the report/comment left if from a long time. If you mention anything, be clear and concise. Not a long discourse, just mention that the site now has a new owner and new (legal) content.

Comment: I am glad the blacklists are all clear. That is good news! The rest should be easy then. Best of Luck! BTW- I have no idea what PatomaS is trying to say. It does not seem clear to me.

Comment: @closetnoc if you are talking about my last comment, I'm talking about the fact that the report was done a long time ago (12/26/2012). So it's relevance is not to high right now for any body that checks the reports. Plus the answer to that comment, doesn't have to be a long and heated rebuttal, is enough just to mention that the site now is different, with a new perspective and new owner. True that I made a few errors on one sentence, it should have been "... comment was left there a long time ago."

Comment: I honestly meant no offense. I really had no idea what you were saying and if it applied to anything I said. Nothing more. I just know that domains with bad reputations can also be in a number of blacklists. I know this because of some of the security analysis research I do. Again.I meant no offense. If I have offended you, I apologize. It was not my intent.

Comment: @closetnoc No problem. And no, I was not replaying to you but to the OP. Since he is notified for each comment, and since I didn't mention you or anything you said, the continuity of discourse makes my comment related to his, specifically, to his question "... should I reply to the comment explaining the situation?"

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13221/discussion-between-patomas-and-closetnoc)

Answer (score 2):

The awful truth I found over the years, was that if your domain was blacklisted, you might as well forget it and start again with a new name. Been there done that!

To "repair" the reputation is nearly impossible and takes forever. Now you've learned how dangerous it is to pick up a "used" domain name. That "beloved" Domain name It isn't as important as we think :-) Just go get a new one for 10 bucks.